# Cucumber is unable to find the Step Definition even it have proper Stepdefinition designed

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

I'm preparing the Selenium Cucumber framework and I'm facing an issue. Step definition path is defined as correct in the glue but it is not able to find the cucumber step definition

**Installed jars:**
Cucumber-java,
Cucumber-core,
Cucumber-junit,
gherkin,
junit,
selenium standalone

**TestRunner**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",glue={"src/test/java/stepDefinitions"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

**Folder Structure**

[image: Folder Structure]

I tried with Cucumber Java 8 but I wasn't even able to get that Given, When, Then annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the glue definition like this:

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/features",
        glue = "stepDefinitions"
)
public class TestRunner{

}
```

Where `stepDefinitions` is a **package name** of your step definition file.

It is not necessary to provide the full path.

Comment: glue is a package name, not a relative path. So `com.example.app` rather then `com/example/app`.